# Limit a Google search to history only

Tags: google-search

In Google, I want to seach for words "rungs" "lunar module" but I want to search only the pages I have visited in the last 7 days.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have [Google History](https://www.google.com/history/) enabled to search your history.

[image: Google History]

Comment: The question was: "how to search only the history".  The answer is not clear yet.